# How do I make knitr print in the same box as its input?

Tags: r, knitr

Knitr separates text and code by putting the code into a box (a table?). Printing a statement will end the previous box and create a new box for the printed statement, which I don't like, however. Using default settings, I get this:

[image: ugly knitr]

whereas I would like to see this (taken from [advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) which seems to be written in knitr as well):

[image: beautiful knitr]

I have read through the documentation but have not been able to find any global / chunk options to do this.

Comment: Just use the option `collapse=TRUE`.

Comment: @wici thanks, I somehow missed that option when looking through the documentation. That's exactly what I was looking for.